# Gather like groups together

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to gather all like groups together in an OU.

Inside of an OU there are 200 groups. of those 200 some share a similar name with -RO, -RW, or -Admin appended onto the end of it.

an example being:

```
TestGroup
TestGroup-Admin
TestGroup-RW
```

Not every group is like this but roughly 50% are. I want to export groups that are like this and groups that are not like this to two different CSV's

So I'll seperate the:

```
TestGroup's
TestGroup-Admin's
TestGroup-RW's
```

From the:

```
NotTestGroup
DifferentTestGroup-Admin
OtherTestGroup
```

I'm trying to do this with an if statement, but I don't know what to compare the CannonicalName against.

So something like:

```
If ($_.CanonicalName -like "otherCannonicalNameInSameOU" ) {
Export-CSV ".\Groups With Similar Names.csv"
}
Else {
Export-CSV ".\Groups With Disimilar Names.csv"
}
```

Thank you kindly for any and all help in advance.

Comment: take a look at `Group-Object`. it can group based on multiple properties AND can group based on calculated properties.

Comment: I'm coming up with Group-Object -property CanonicalName | ? CanonicalName -like "CanonicalName?*" but i can already see it won't grab the original in that, unless there is a way I am unaware of?

Comment: i may not be understanding your intent. [*blush*] would you please show several lines of items and how you want them grouped? show the input list, the output from that list, and the basis of the grouping.

Comment: Say I have the CanonicalName, Created, Description, ManagedBy, Member, MemberOf, Members, ObjectGUID, and whenChanged of an AD group.                     Domain/Groups/GroupsGroups/Groups/TestGroup-Power-User, Domain/Groups/GroupsGroups/Groups/TestGroup-Admin, Domain/Groups/GroupsGroups/Groups/TestGroup-RO, Domain/Groups/GroupsGroups/Groups/OtherGroup-Power-User, Domain/Groups/GroupsGroups/Groups/LimitedGroup-Power-User, Domain/Groups/GroupsGroups/Groups/NotTestGroup.  I want the groups that share name but have different "Tags" grouped together

Comment: please, add that info to the Question - and use code formatting. i can't make any sense of the current garbled display. [*blush*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you acquired your group list. If we assume you have group objects stored in `$groups`, you can do something like the following.

```
$targetGroup = '/My Group Name$'
$output = $groups | Group-Object {$_.CanonicalName -replace '^(.*/.*?)(-RW|-RO|-Admin)?$','$1'}
$output | Where Name -match $targetGroup | Select Group |
    Export-Csv -Path CSVWithGroup.csv -NoType
$output | Where Name -notmatch $targetGroup | Select Group |
    Export-Csv -Path CSVWithOtherGroups.csv -NoType
```

**Explanation:**

Since `Group-Object`'s `-Property` parameter can accept a script block, you can do some manipulation to a property value to do a custom grouping.

`-replace` performs a regex match and followed by a string replace of that match. `^(.*/.*?)(-RW|-RO|-Admin)?$` is the regex pattern with the following breakdown:

- `^`: Start of the string
- `(.*/.*?)`: `.*` matches 0 or more characters greedily. `/` is a literal backslash. `.*?` matches 0 or more characters lazily. The `()` creates capture group 1 since it is the first parenthetical grouping. This match is referenced in the replace string as `$1`.
- `(-RW|-RO|-Admin)?`: `-RW` is literal `-RW`. `|` is regex `or`. `?` is match the previous character or group 0 or 1 time. `?` applies to the entire `(-RW|-RO|-Admin)` group. `()` creates capture group 2. Capture group 2 match can be referenced in the replace string as `$2`, but we don't need it here.
- `$`: End of the string.

`Group-Object` outputs a `GroupInfo` object. That object contains the properties `Count`, `Name`, and `Group`. `Count` is the number of groups you have based on your `-Property` value passed to `Group-Object`. `Name` is the `-Property` value. `Group` contains the object(s) that was originally piped into `Group-Object`. This is why we use `Select Group` so that we can output the original objects within that grouping. Each `Group` will contain a collection of those grouped objects, which will ultimately be a subset of `$groups`.

Because you will have multiple grouped objects inside of `$output`, you can loop through them if you wanted to process something against each group. `$output | Foreach-Object { }` is a common way to loop through the groupings. Within the `Foreach-Object` script block, `$_.Name` would be the group property and `$_.Group` would be all of the original objects within that grouping.